# Cannot resolve symbol 'ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION'

Tags: android

Actually I'm trying to make my existing app compatible on Android-10 (Q). Below is how I set compile and target sdk versions in my build.gradle file--

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 83
        versionName "83.0"
        multiDexEnabled true;
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

and below are the support library dependencies I'm using after migrating my app to Android-X

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
```

I'm done migrating my project to Android-X, also installed Android9.+ (Q) API-Level 29 from sdk manager and still I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol 'ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION'" error. I request you to guide me to resolve this issue. Also please let me know if I can provide more details for the same. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: How do you import `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`?

Comment: ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION was added in API level 29, which may contradict to your `minSdkVersion 17` setting.

Comment: and you may get better luck specifying the full name as `android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`

Comment: Can you post the code that is generating this error?

Answer (score 2):

### When targeting Android 9 or lower

If your app requests either **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** or **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**, the system automatically adds **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** to the request.

### Access when device is upgraded to Android 10

If a user grants your app access to device location – either **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** or **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** – then upgrades their device from Android 9 to Android 10, the system automatically updates the set of location-based permissions granted to your app. The set of permissions that your app receives after the upgrade depends on its target SDK version and its defined permissions.

Read official guideline [**`Privacy changes in Android 10`**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes).

if you target SDK 29+ and want to access locations in the background, you should  add below in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

### Runtime Permission

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 99;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION = 100;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
    {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {

                        // Dialog for grant Permission
                    }
                    else {

                       // Dialog for Required permission

                    }

                }
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message to which you refer is related to the privacy policies related to permissions on Android. Android 10 introduces the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission. The API level 29 specifies that access to the location of the device in the background requires this permissions. For this you need to set the `targetSdkVersion` or `compileSdkVersion` to `29` or higher. 
Try to make the permission explicit in the **Manifest** to get permissions in foreground and background

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```